# If $A,B \in M_{m \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ have the same column space, then there exists $C \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A = BC$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading the following article(http://mlwiki.org/index.php/Gram-Schmidt_Process#QR_Factorization), and it seems make the following assertion: if $A,B \in M_{m \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ have the same column space, then there exists $C \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A = BC$. Could someone offer or direct me to a proof?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ having the same column space implies that each column of $A$, $\mathbf a_j$, is in the column space of $B$ which means $\mathbf a_j = \sum_{k=1}^n c_k^{(j)} \mathbf b_k$.  This holds for every column $j$, thus $BC=A$.

Comment: all we need is for ther rank of $B$ to be at least the rank of $A$.

Comment: @JorgeFernández-Hidalgo If you're commenting on the proof given in the previous comment, then this clearly holds by symmetry (i.e. we could switch the roles of $A$ and $B$).

Comment: I'm commenting on the problem in general. But I made a mistake I hadn't see the order of $B$ and $C$.